# Insert value to every other array index in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, insertion

I need to turn an array of integers like `[1,2,3]` into an array in which the integers are each followed by a zero: `[1,0,2,0,3,0]`.

My best guess, which works but looks jenky:

```
> [1,2,3].flat_map{|i| [i,0]} => [1,0,2,0,3,0]
```

Comment: imo, `flat_map` is ideal. It's efficient and reads well. Had you not mentioned it I would have given it as an answer. btw, your question is only implied. Best to always state the question.

Comment: `[i, 0]` expresses _"integers are each followed by a zero"_ pretty well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) works pretty well, one might avoid the pre-creation of zeroes array by using [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
[1,2,3].product([0]).flatten
```

or, just use a reducer:

```
[1,2,3].each_with_object([]) { |e, acc| acc << e << 0 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty straight forward with [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip):

```
a = (1..10).to_a

b = Array.new(a.length, 0)

a.zip(b).flatten
# => [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0]
```

Comment: You should inline b, imo.

Comment: When I see `Array.new` construct I always fear that I suddenly woke up in javascript land :) `b = [0] * a.size`?

Comment: @mudasobwa JavaScript's `new Array()` and that one is far more unpredictable as `new Array(10)` is an array of length 10, while `new Array (10, 11)` is a two element array. The Ruby one is more consistent: `Array.new(size=0, default=nil)`

Comment: `b = [0].cycle`

Answer (score 0):

This seems same as yours -))

```
[1,2,3].map {|i| [i, 0] }.flatten
```

Also this.

```
 [1,2,3].collect {|x| [x, 0] }.flatten
```

Ugly and uneffective solution.

```
 [1,2,3].join("0").split("").push(0).map{|s| s.to_i }
```

Comment: `map` in an alias for `collect`, that said first two are exactly same. The latter won’t work for 2-digits numbers.